# Adding a column with a calculation to multiple CSVs

Tags: pandas

I'm SUPER green to Python and am having some issues trying to automate some calculations.

I know that this works to add a new column called "Returns" that divides "value" of current to "value" of previous to a csv:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
a = pd.read_csv("/Data/a_data.csv", index_col = "time")    
a ["Returns"] = (a["value"]/a["value"].shift(1) -1)*100
```

However, I have a lot of these CSVs. I need this calculation to happen prior to merging them all together. So I was hoping to write something that just looped through all of the CSVs and did the calculation and added the column but clearly this was incorrect as I get Syntax error:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import csv
a = pd.read_csv("/Data/a_data.csv", index_col = "time")
b = pd.read_csv("/Data/b_data.csv", index_col = "time")
c = pd.read_csv("/Data/c_data.csv", index_col = "time")
my_lists = ['a','b','c']

for my_list in my_lists:
    {my_list}["Returns"] = ({my_list}["close"]/{my_list}["close"].shift(1) -1)*100
    print(f"Calculating: {my_list.upper()}")
```

I'm sure there is an easy way to do this that I just haven't reached in my Python education yet, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest you don't put `{my_list}` inside curly braces unless you're using an f-string. I think that's what is causing your syntax error.

Comment: Thanks Nick. When I remove the curly brackets I get a traceback error saying: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Assuming "*close*" and "*time*" are fields defined in **each** of your csv files, you could define a function that reads each file, do the shift and returns a dataframe:

```py
def your_func(my_file):  # this function takes a file name as an argument. 
    my_df = pd.read_csv(my_file, index_col = "time")  # The function reads its content into a data frame,
    my_df["Returns"] = (my_df["close"]/{my_df}["close"].shift(1) -1)*100  #  makes the calculation 
    return my_df   #and returns it as an output.
```

2. Then as a main code, you  collect all csv files from a folder with *glob* package. Using the above function, you build a data frame for each file with the calculation done.

```py
    import glob  
    path =r'/Data/'  # path to the directory where you have the csv files
    filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")  # grab the csv files names using glob package with path+all csv files present 
    for filename in filenames:  # loop into all csv files names in the list of csv files present in the directory
        df= your_func (filename) # call the function, defined above block of code,  that reads the file from its name as argument, then makes the calculation and returns it. 
        print (df)
```

Above, there is a print of the data Frame which shows results; I am not sure what you intend to do with *upper* (I dont think this is a function on a data frame).
Finally, this returns independent data frames with calculations done prior to other or final transformation.

Comment: Thanks Jerome, this actually makes sense to someone in pre-school Python class! Yes, "time" and "close" are both column headings present in each and every CSV. The only thing I don't understand is how to feed your suggested use of my_file with a list of all the files?

Comment: @jrcart the first block of ode is to define the function that takes a file name and returns the data frame. The second block contains a "for loop" on a list of file names (files names gathered with the package glob that reads all csv files from a specific folder). Basically each file in the filenames list (filenames) are truned into a data frame through function "your_func". Let me add some comments on the answer. I hope that will help.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thank you for the explanations. That is super helpful and makes a ton of sense. Thank you so much for your help @Jerome!

Comment: out of curiosity, would it be possible to use .to_csv to then overwrite the previous files with this new version?

Comment: nm, I answered my own question... I added the following and it worked like a charm:
 df.to_csv(filename, header=True, index=True)

Answer (score 1):

1.Do a, b, c data frames have the same dimension?

2.You don't need to import the CSV library because it includes in the Pandas library.

3.If you want to union data frames, you can use like this :

```
my_lists = [a,b,c]
```

and you can concatenate with this way:

```
result=pd.concat(my_lists)
```

Lastly, your calculation should be :

```
result["Returns"]=(result.loc[:, "close"].div(result.loc[:, "close"].shift()).fillna(0).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0))
```

You need to add an index-label selection (`loc`) function to the data frame in order to access the values. When numbers are dividing, results can be NaN(Not a Number) or infinite. Therefore, `replace` and `fillna` functions are related to NaN and Inf.

Comment: Thank you. 
1. They all have the same column headings
2. OK, thanks.
3. OK, but it appears to me that you're joining them first before doing the calculation. The calculation must happen prior to concatenating the CSVs together. This is why I was trying to do a loop of some sort.